# Как отобразить окно MainWindow. С# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Как отобразить окно **MainWindow**, после того как его закрыли командой `this.Close`. Мне нужно открыть его в новом окне **Window1**. 
Пробовал кодом:

```
MainWindow window = new MainWindow();
window.Show();
```

Выдавало ошибку:

> ***Серьезность Код    Описание    Проект  Файл    Строка  Состояние подавления Ошибка     не удалось скопировать "obj\Debug\BdBegin.exe" в
>   "bin\Debug\BdBegin.exe". Превышено допустимое число повторных попыток
>   (10). Произошел сбой. "BdBegin (20124)" блокирует этот файл   BdBegin***

Как решить эту проблему?)

Comment: убить предыдущий процесс запущенного  BdBegin.exe

Comment: Да, спасибо @vitidev

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка была из-за того, что был запущен **exe-шник**.
А чтобы скрыть основное окно **MainWindow**. Достаточно создать экземпляр класса **MainWindow**, в нужном окне и там отображать MainWindow свойством **Visible**, а в основном окне сделать **Collapsed**;

Новое окно:

```
MainWindow anyname = new MainWindow();
anyname.Visibility = Visibility.Visible
```

Основное окно(Главное):

```
this.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
```